# How to configure NBug to send email

Tags: wpf, nbug

I have a WPF application that I would like to configure to use [NBug](https://github.com/soygul/NBug) to send error reports via email.

The config tool works correctly, and I receive a test email, but when adding NBug to the application and triggering an uncaught exception, I do not receive an email.  The only configuration I have done matches the Getting Started guide (loosely translated to VB.Net).

```
Private Sub Application_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, NBug.Handler.UnhandledException
    AddHandler Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException, NBug.Handler.DispatcherUnhandledException
    AddHandler TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException, NBug.Handler.UnobservedTaskException

    NBug.Settings.UIMode = NBug.Enums.UIMode.Full
    NBug.Settings.StoragePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    NBug.Settings.AddDestinationFromConnectionString("Type=Mail;From=bugs@xxx.com;Port=465;SmtpServer=smtp.gmail.com;To=support@xxx.com;UseAttachment=True;UseAuthentication=True;UseSsl=True;Username=bugs@xxx.com;Password=xxx;")
    NBug.Settings.ReleaseMode = True

End Sub
```

The above code has removed username/password from our gmail account that is used for bug reports.

Any ideas what is wrong with the config or how I could debug?

The zip file attachment is being generated, but no email is sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `NBug.Settings.ReleaseMode = true;` as described in this intro post: http://www.soygul.com/nbug/

Comment: Thanks.  I edited the post to include the ReleaseMode flag which did not solve my issue.

Comment: Then enable the logger with the configurator tool and see what is happening internally. There can be lots of things going wrong (permission issues, write errors, etc.)